# GROUP BY de los últimos registros en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Qisiera Obtener el ultimo registro de una tabla de llamadas que realizan diferentes clientes, para esto tengo 2 tablas una donde esta el registro de los clientes y la otra que se relaciona de llamadas, estas se relacionan por medio de el id del cliente (id_marketing)

Consulta

```
SELECT * FROM marketing as u

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT b2.id_marketing, b2.estado_id, MAX(b2.id_llamadas_marketing) as id_ultima_llamada FROM llamadas_marketing as b2 group by b2.id_marketing
) AS j2 ON j2.id_marketing = u.id_marketing
```

[image: Tabla marketing]

[image: Tabla llamadas_marketing]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven la consulta me trae el id_ultima_llamada y los datos como nombre y apellido pero el estado trae el primero que se registro por defecto y deberia traer 7 , 9 y 11 respectivamente. he intentado la consulta con la ultima fecha de modificacion y sucede lo mismo.Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: quieres utilizar el max?

Comment: no necesariamente aunque con la ayuda de @Okyam funcuiona perfectamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola estuve probando el query que tenias y al parecer me muestra el mismo inconveniente, me di cuenta que al ejecutar la tabla intermedia que creaste para hacer el join, la tabla usa el primer estatus de la tabla llamadas y no el estatus de la ultima llamada. esto debe de pasar por que la función max esta independiente de los otros campos, agrupa te trae la llamada mas alta pero toma el primer valor del estatus.

Mira este query me funciono bien con unas tablas que cree.

```
 SELECT 
 u.*,
(select max(id_llamadas_marketing) from llamadas_marketing where id_marketing=u.id_marketing group by id_marketing)  ultima_llamada,
(select estado_id from llamadas_marketing where id_llamadas_marketing=ultima_llamada group by id_marketing)  estado
FROM marketing u 
WHERE u.id_marketing in (select id_marketing from llamadas_marketing);
```

Cambie los campos por los que tenias, espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba y con tu explicacion me quedo claro el error.

Acabo de implementarla desde php y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Siempre a  la orden

Comment: Disculpen el Select u.* a que se refiere

Comment: Quiere decir que se van a seleccionar todas las columnas de la tabla marketing a la cual se le asigno el alias "u"